# I wrote the code correctly, but cant figure out how to make a better design with arrays.CS50

Tags: cs50

I wrote the code correctly. But can't figure out how to make it better designed and use arrays. I can't put arrays in the code even if I have the idea how I would use them.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int BITS_IN_BYTE = 8;

void print_bulb(int bit);

int main(void)
{
    // TODO
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int lenght = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        char letter = text[i];
        int number = letter;
        int n[8];
        for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            int binary = number;
            int b2 = number / 2;
            int b3 = b2 / 2;
            int b4 = b3 / 2;
            int b5 = b4 / 2;
            int b6 = b5 / 2;
            int b7 = b6 / 2;
            int b8 = b7 / 2;
            int binarym = binary % 2;
            int bm2 = b2 % 2;
            int bm3 = b3 % 2;
            int bm4 = b4 % 2;
            int bm5 = b5 % 2;
            int bm6 = b6 % 2;
            int bm7 = b7 % 2;
            int bm8 = b8 % 2;
            print_bulb(bm8);
            print_bulb(bm7);
            print_bulb(bm6);
            print_bulb(bm5);
            print_bulb(bm4);
            print_bulb(bm3);
            print_bulb(bm2);
            print_bulb(binarym);
            printf("\n");

        }
        //printf("%i ", number);
    }

}

void print_bulb(int bit)
{
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        // Dark emoji
        printf("\U000026AB");
    }
    else if (bit == 1)
    {
        // Light emoji
        printf("\U0001F7E1");
    }
}
```

When you input text code should take every letter and make it binary then print binary as black emoji for 0 and yellow emoji for 1.

Comment: First, replace `b0, ..., b9` with `b[0], ..., b[9]`. When defining, use `int b[10];` (array of 10 elements is considered a single element) instead of `int b0, b1, b2, ...., b9;`. Now you have code repeating like `a[0] = b[0] / 2; a[1] = b[1] / 2; ...`. Use a `for` loop so it runs the same piece of code substituting different integers inside the square brackets.